# can a single executable for a node.js application access a file not present in its modules

Tags: javascript

The Executable makes a virtual folder and the whole javascript module is present in that folder. I want to keep all the paths and resource names in a certain text file and access it from my main function. But as the text file is not present in the virtual folder the executable can't access it. Is there any way I can do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the *executable* creates the virtual directory (presumably a symbolic link) then it should be able to access outside of the virtual directory at some/any point. You can use [fs](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html) to move/pull the data of your text file.